# andFilterWhere with OR LIKE from array

Tags: php, yii2

This are keywords

```
$keywords = ['html','css','js','php','yii2']
```

And this is **Yii** query filter from model

```
$query->orFilterWhere(["LIKE","skill_name",$val]);
```

And it gives below results

```
WHERE `skill_name` LIKE '%html%'
   AND `skill_name` LIKE '%css%'
   AND `skill_name` LIKE '%js%'
   AND `skill_name` LIKE '%php%'
   AND `skill_name` LIKE '%yii2%'
```

I want this query after where

```
WHERE `skill_name` LIKE '%html%'
   OR `skill_name` LIKE '%css%'
   OR `skill_name` LIKE '%js%'
   OR `skill_name` LIKE '%php%'
   OR `skill_name` LIKE '%yii2%'
```

Comment: please select the answer by taking out some time as a good gesture towards the person who is helping you out by giving you some of his time, happy SO :).

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `or like` for such cases:

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['OR LIKE', 'skill_name', $val]);
```

See https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-queryinterface#where()-detail

---

`or` in `orFilterWhere()` defines how to join new condition to existing conditions. So if you have:

```
$query->orFilterWhere('some condition 1')->orFilterWhere('some condition 2');
```

It will generate something like:

```
WHERE some condition 1 OR some condition 2
```

The `OR` between condition comes from `orFilterWhere()`.

Comment: and $val is probably $keywords you don't have to use foreach